# pop up image on mouse over position css

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm using [this script](http://www.nicolashoening.de/?twocents&nr=8) to do some mouse over image pop up, but the script shows the image on the top right of the mouse, is it possible to set a specific coordinates, or even force the image to drop to the bottom right?

/css

```
  #pup {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:200; /* aaaalways on top*/
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.95em;
}
```

//html

```
<a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('<?php echo $q; ?>: <br/><br/> <img src=&quot;../specials/<?php echo $logo; ?>&quot;/>', {'width': 250});">Logo</a>
```

if you guys need me to provide any of there other code, i can, but i think the css is all you need, not sure. also i want to mention that this text for this pop up is within a table row, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about CSS and you do not show the demo.

what you have to do is set your #pup in absolute. (You have it, but you don't set the right and bottom)

```
  #pup {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; /* this is make your image have a (0,0) coordinate */
  z-index:200; /* aaaalways on top*/
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.95em;
}
```

More about position: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

And **do not forget** to make #pup HTML parent set to position relative.

**For example,** If #pup have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="pup">
  <!-- This is yours -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {position:relative;}
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it creates the pop up box length to be insanely large